# Switch statement behavior in C++

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm having trouble understanding my C++ switch statement.

I have to enter the accepted integer interval twice for the function to return to the switch. And then it falls straight through to case 2.

**Inherited Class:**

```
class Fugl : public DyrLuft
{
  private:
    int alder;

  public:
    Fugl() : DyrLuft()
      { }                                         
    void les()
      { 
      do
        {
        cout << "\nSkriv inn fuglens alder: ";
        cin >> alder;
        if(alder < 0 || alder > 130)
          cout << "\nDenne alderen virket usannsynlig, prøv igjen!\n";
        } while(alder < 0 || alder > 130);
      }
};
```

**Main:**

```
int main()
{
  char valg = '\q';
  cout << "Hvilken dyreart ønsker du å registrere? (Q for å avslutte)"
    << "\n1) - Fugl \n2) - Fisk \n3) - Insekt \n4) - Skalldyr\n"; 
  do
    {
    cin >> valg;
    switch(valg)
      {
      case '1':
        {
        Fugl fugl; fugl.les();
        } break;
      case '2':
        {
        Fisk fisk; fisk.les();
        } break;
      case '3':
        {
        Insekt insekt; insekt.les();
        } break;
      case '4':
        {
        Skalldyr skalldyr; skalldyr.les();
        } break;
      case 'Q': return 0;
      case 'q': return 0;
      default: cout << "Velg en av ovennevnte!\n";
      }
    } while(valg != 'Q' || valg != 'q');
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what are the inputs?

Comment: Is `"\nDenne alderen virket usannsynlig, prøv igjen!\n"` printed in between inputting `alder`?

Comment: `char valg = '\q';` seems wrong, but it shouldn't be the reason of your problem, as `valg` is soon overwritten... Also, what's in `DyrLuft()`? This gets called when you declare `Fugl fugl;`.

Comment: If I input a value larger than 130 or less than 0:  `cout << "\nDenne alderen virket usannsynlig, prøv igjen!\n";` appears. Then it repeats until I enter an integer between these limits. But that is the number I have to enter twice.

Comment: Not the cause of this problem, but "valg is not 'Q' or valg is not 'q'", does not mean the same as "valg is not one of 'Q' or 'q'".

Comment: It's meant to leave the do{}while if q or Q is typed. Switch cases also returns 0 if this happens.

Comment: Could you post the copy/paste of your terminal? Just so we know what messages are printed and what inputs are provided.

Comment: the code looks fine, except for the fact that the condition in your while is nonsensical. You should replace the || with && and get rid of the 'Q' and 'q' cases -> than your code will also be easier to understand

Comment: Maybe it's an ASCII vs. unicode issue?  He's being a bit free and easy with the switch argument.  It should really be an int and the cases as ints.

Comment: [link](http://i58.tinypic.com/2hyl5xs.png) here's an image of the entire program plus the terminal, it stops at the end and stays there with no further changes

Comment: Seems to be waiting for input at `cin >> valg;`. Can you input anything more at this stage?

Comment: No. Further inputs results in no numbers, letters or similar showing up in the terminal. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is happening in your case, but I ran your code and it works just fine for me. Entered 1,4,Q and program exited as expected....Could be a compiler or a DyrLuft class issue(i just removed the inheritance to make it work, also lines from case 2,3,4).

Comment: I tried removing all other classes and replaced the rest of the cases with simple cout << statements. Now the program stops responding after I've typed an accepted integer value in case 1. So my try computer reboot / compiler reinstallation?

Comment: Tried computer reboot without luck. Could it be a compiler problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
case '1':
        {
        Fugl fugl; fugl.les();
        } break;
```

When you run this you create a Fug1 object and then you call the `les()` function.  When you enter an appropriate age in `les()` the function returns.  Since the `break;` is outside of the case block it is actually breaking the switch statement and going to the end of the loop.  Then it cycles back to the top of the loop and makes you enter a selection again.  If you move break inside og the case block it functions as it should.  This is the changed loop:

```
do
    {
        cout << "Hvilken dyreart ønsker du å registrere? (Q for å avslutte)"
            << "\n1) - Fugl \n2) - Fisk \n3) - Insekt \n4) - Skalldyr\n";
        cin >> valg;
        switch (valg)
        {
        case '1':
        {
                    Fugl fugl; fugl.les(); 
                    break;
        } 
        case '2':
        {
                    Fisk fisk; fisk.les();
                    break;
        }
        case '3':
        {
                    Insekt insekt; insekt.les();
                    break;
        }
        case '4':
        {
                    Skalldyr skalldyr; skalldyr.les();
                    break;
        } 
        case 'Q': return 0;
        case 'q': return 0;
        default: cout << "Velg en av ovennevnte!\n";
        }
    } while (valg != 'Q' || valg != 'q');
```

Comment: No, it does not break out of the loop.

Comment: @molbdnilo:  I edited it to say that is breaking out of the switch statement.  Mind and fingers were out of sync.

Comment: I tried moving the break inside the brackets with the same result.

Comment: @Thomas: did you move the `cout` statement inside the loop as well?